# Query of Queries always returns 0 records?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfquery, coldfusion-2016, cfinvoke

I have code that worked just fine on ColdFusion 9 but once we did an update to ColdFusion 2016 the code stooped working. Here is an example of the code:

```
<cfset rec = structKeyExists(URL, "recType") ? recType : "">

<cfinvoke component="#application.pathIDEA#.APPS.components.getRecs" method="evalSelect" returnvariable="getEvalData">
    <cfinvokeargument name="whKey" value="#key#"/>
    <cfinvokeargument name="whType" value="#rec#"/>
</cfinvoke>

<cfdump var="#getEvalData.recordcount#">

<cfquery name="evalData" dbtype="query">
    SELECT *
    FROM getEvalData
    <cfif len(rec) AND rec NEQ 9>
        WHERE ea_type = '#rec#'
    </cfif>
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#evalData.recordcount#">
```

As you can see above I have `cfinvoke` that calls a function in my `.cfc`. If I dump my return variable there is data with 20 records. Once I use `query of queries` to add the filter for `ea_type` field the query will return 0 records. I'm confused why that would return 0 since data exist for that type. Is there something in ColdFusion 2016 that works different or my code is breaking for some other reason. Again this worked in ColdFusion 9 and ColdFusion 10 but doesn't work in ColdFusion 2016. If anyone knows how this can be fixed please let me know.

Comment: The code looks okay. What does the data look like? Does the `rec` variable have data that is not equal to `9` and there are no rows where the `ea_type` column is equal to the `rec` value?

Comment: @Miguel-F Data exist and I have checked with cfdump. Also I have tested my code and replaced query of queries method with regular query and just added the filter for ea_type field. Then everything works fine. it's odd that we haven't touched the code since upgrade and this doesn't work. So definitely something is different in new version of ColdFusion.

Comment: @espresso_coffee Query-of-Queries are case-sensitive. Have you tried using `lower()` & `LCase()` so that you are comparing the same values?  Is `ea_type` an integer? If so, you may want to use `JavaCast("int", val(rec))` when comparing (and also test to verify that it's an valid INT before running the SQL or it will throw an invalid datatype error.)

Comment: I created a simple test with your code that seems to work fine - [TryCF gist](https://trycf.com/gist/942c4bbcc39432352b78735e1b293bd1/acf2016?theme=monokai)  Maybe you can plug in some of your data and see if it ever fails. Or change the data types as James is referring to. I made them INT in my test code.

Comment: Is `recType` defined somewhere else in the page? You're checking if it exists in the URL, but then assigning an unscoped variable to `rec`. Try dumping `rec` before you drop it in your query. Also, try changing `recType` to `url.recType`.

Comment: @espresso_coffee - please post a sanitized dump showing 1) the actual values of both variables - `#getEvalData#` and `#rec#` values 2) and the data types `#rec.getClass().getName()#` and `#getEvalData.ea_type# #getEvalData.ea_type[1].getClass().getName()#`

Comment: Whenever this sort of thing happens to me, the cause is usually whitespace.

Comment: I have tried everything you mentioned above (checking rec value type, using url.recType) and still doesn't work. If I use regular query instead of query of queries everything works fine. Just weird ....

Comment: "checking rec value type" @espresso_coffee - I think we've gone as far as we can go without more specifics ;-) What were the results of your check? Please post the results and some sample data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180248/query-of-queries-always-returns-0-records#comment85401498_49180248

Comment: When you delete the <cfif>, does the query of queries return 20 rows?

Comment: @SeanHogge Yes it does. I tried that too, removing cfif and setting hard coded value but still query of queries returns 0.

Comment: Is there a chance that the invoke returns an object that isn't a query object but still responds to .recordCount? I don't work in ACF2016, so I don't know if structures might respond to recordCount or something weird like that.

Comment: @SeanHogge That's what I was suspicious about. If I replace query of queries with SQL statement that is used in cf invoke call everything works fine. AT the same time I cf-dump invoke result and all looks good. I get 20 records with all information about that query... I think that something is different in CF16 then previous versions with cfinvoke (what and how returns result).

Comment: Also try replacing your invoke with a query in the page, then do the query of queries. That'll tell you that CF2016 is returning the query object oddly, or that something is up with QofQ. Or maybe you already tried that? If so then it's definitely QofQ that has something new.

Comment: @SeanHogge I have tried that too. Weird is that nothing is on adobe site about not supporting query of queries or any major changes...

Comment: As a last ditch effort, change your = to a LIKE. I'm just going on hunches at this point.

Comment: @SeanHogge I will try that too. thanks for your time and help!

Comment: @SeanHogge - A LIKE will probably behave the same as equals, unless they add some wildcards. *just going on hunches at this point* Yeah, guessing is pretty much all anyone can do at this point, since we can't see any of the query data or values...

Comment: @Ageax I'm not sure that a LIKE and an = behave the same when it comes to case sensitivity.

Comment: @SeanHogge - They do.  The database (or dbtype) is the determining factor, not the LIKE operator.  QoQ's are always case sensitive. https://trycf.com/gist/dbe05d25528f69757cea2d26f39ebba3/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: @Ageax The determining factor (database type) wasn't included in the original post. Thus LIKE and = may not behave the same in this specific situation, especially with trailing whitespace but possibly with case sensitivity (however unlikely). I apologize if my brevity caused any confusion for anyone.

Comment: @SeanHogge - Sorry, I meant dbms (for regular query) or dbtype (for QoQ). According to the OP, it's a QoQ. QoQ's are always case sensitive.  With standard databases, LIKE and "=" shouldn't behave any differently regarding white space, unless wild cards are involved. But ... this is a QoQ, so it depends on how Adobe implemented them and unfortunately that's changed in different versions. So you could be right about there being differences in this specific case. That said, it's impossible to know without seeing data samples and knowing which version they're using.